# ClearOut Value in OpenArgs

Tags: vba, ms-access

I feel like I'm not doing something right here.  I open and load an unbound form (form2) from a double-click of a lstbox in form 1 using OpenArgs in a SQL statement in the OnOpen and OnLoad events.  I also have a button that clears out all objects on that form in case I want to enter a new record on form2, the same one I populated with the OpenArgs.  But because OpenArgs is read-only, it keeps the OpenArg value from form1... and I can't seem to clear it out, I get an error saying I can't change the value of a read-only field... fine.

So I just assigned the OpenArg to an invisible textbox and clear out the textbox.  Then I can use the textbox instead of the OpenArgs should I choose to do so.

Is there a way to clear out OpenArgs so that when I use form2 to enter a new record it doesn't think I'm reusing the OpenArgs from form1?

Comment: Not sure I got your problem: OpenArgs are only used on Opening the form, and just once. When you want to call it again, first close form2 and then open it again whith the new OpenArgs.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately :)), OpenArgs is read-only.

You can use the Tag property (I use it constantly) if you want to modify some form parameters or `properties, and use it as if it were the OpenArgs property (programming it properly on Current event or similar).

Comment: In what event are you using OpenArgs? Why would you not want to use it for a new record? Use an If Then test `If Me.NewRecord Then`.

Comment: I would only use it for updating and viewing existing records.  I also create new records using the same form which means I have to clear all objects out and save whatever the user puts in there, I am simply clearing out the form by looping through all of the textbox controls.  But when I save I can't clear out the text box so it errors on the loop that cleared everything out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been sick.


In my opinion, it is a mistake to use the same form to edit, add and view at the same time.
It has triple work, but the results are much better

Can you give me an example code of what you want to do?